# Random Data Generator using Yaml File

Tags: java, yaml

I'm trying to generate random data from a yaml file

```
  dog:
    name: ["Buddy", "Max", "Bella", "Daisy"]
    breed: ["Affenpinscher", "Pug", "Airedale", "Akita"]
    age: ["puppy", "young", "adult", "senior"]
    gender: ["female", "male"]
```

But I'm having some difficulties using `com.fasterxml.jackson` and this is my first time using yaml.
I already have a class `Dog` which has the `name, breed, age, gender` as fields.
I need it as a list `List<Dog>`. How can I generate a random `List` of dogs using the provided Yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a class called dog that has this variables as member of type list.
Then you can read the yaml into this object and access the attributes.

```
public class Dog{
 private List<String> name;
private List<String> breed;
private List<String> age;
private List<String> gender;

//getters and setters
}
```

Then you can read via Jackson.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
InputStream  dogFile = new FileInputStream("dog.yaml");
Dog dog = objectMapper.readValue(dogFile,Dog.class);
```

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for sorry. This is simply a `Dog` with a list of variables, not a random list of `Dogs`

Comment: No this is a class that contains your list specified in the yaml. From there you can create random dogs by selecting random indices of the lists. You will not be able to create random objects directly from the yaml file, jackson can only map the file to an object